# How can I uninstall Spotify forever?

Tags: uninstall, spotify

I have a problem in my pc, I want to uninstall Spotify but I’m not able to do that.

[image]

I used Synaptic to do it but didn’t work for me.

I want to uninstall it because its the preview version, the old one, and every time I tried to install Spotify its the same old version 0.9.4.183.g644e24e0.

[image]

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: How you installed?

Comment: After uninstalling from synaptic Use this command `sudo rm -rf /opt/spotify/`

Comment: I installed from the official page https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/

Comment: Is there any change after following my second comment!

Comment: The app in opt folder its gone, thanks :) , but I have a question why in my apps still appearing? http://i.imgur.com/BLnitfJ.png

Comment: Right clickon that icon ! wwhat you see ?

Comment: Use this command `sudo rm /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop`

Comment: "No image available" http://i.imgur.com/PmqJ612.png , ok i will try with that command, I think my problem is this 

https://github.com/SecUpwN/Spotify-AdKiller,  I installed this app but idk how to remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28998/discussion-between-nesticle-and-ravan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling Spotify using Synaptic run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/spotify/ /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop
```

(This command removes the icon of the uninstalled application.)

Note : Also refer and proceed according our [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28998/discussion-between-nesticle-and-ravan).